# How to Open PDF file from First page in android

Tags: java, javascript, android, pdf

I want to display PDF file from First Page in android

Now i displayed PDF file using below Code.After reopen the pdf it display current page not redirect the first page.

How to redirect the first page in PDF in android?

```
Intent intent  = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in android but have you tried using `android:noHistory="true"`? You can set this on your manifest file. As I understand on this, it prevents your app from resuming.

Documentation:

android:noHistory

Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false".

A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html